# xml tag can consists of integer values or can contains special characters?

Tags: .net, xml

For example.
Are these xml tags acceptable or not.

```
<xml>
<3333>abc</3333>
<ab#$3>def</ab#$3>
</xml>
```

My question is can I create tags of integers values or a tag with Special characters ?

I tried this

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream((filename), FileMode.Append);
XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(fs);
w.WriteStartElement("3454");
```

and got the following error
`{System.ArgumentException: Invalid name character in '3454'. The '3' character, hexadecimal value 0x33, cannot be included in a name.
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.CheckNCName(String ncname)
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String ns)
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteStartElement(String localName)
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.fn_setMapping(SqlString keyString, SqlString column, SqlString value)`

Thank You

Comment: I somehow sense some horrible design lurking behind this question.

Comment: Filburt I'm new to xml. Not know the rules for xml. The reason behind this question :)

Comment: If you plan to put logic into the names of Xml node names by adding numbers you're doing it wrong and will experience lots of trouble later when you want to process your Xml data. Use attributes instead: Don't do this: `<Name1>Foo</Name1>` rather do this: `<Name nametype="1">Foo</Name>`

Comment: I sometimes try to think: why is this person asking this question? And for the life of me, I don't know. Are you having trouble finding the information in the specs? Is there conflicting information somewhere? Surely you're not asking because you're too lazy to look it up?

Comment: you are right. I never see the specs and one thing, It is not easy to find the required information in a large specs, it takes time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An XML element name cannot start with a number, so `<3333>` is not valid.

As for which special characters are valid... see the [spec for element names](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name).

```
NameStartChar      ::=      ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
NameChar       ::=      NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
Name       ::=      NameStartChar (NameChar)*
```

A valid name should start with a `NameStartChar` followed by any number of `NameChar`.

Comment: and what about special characters ? and also share the links for xml rules if you have

Comment: @WaqarJanjua - So long as they fall within the allowed range. See updated answer.

Comment: is it possible to check a string value is a valid xml tag or not ?

Comment: @WaqarJanjua - You can try to create an [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) with that name. If it throws, it is invalid.

Comment: Thanks Oded. Well i'm not using LINQ

Comment: @WaqarJanjua - `XmlElement` should also throw.